# Extend a propel model class

Tags: php, oop, orm, propel

As it is described thoroughly in [the propel documentation](http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html#generate-model-classes), propel generates a base class, e.g., `Base\Foo` that is extended by an individual class `Foo`. The same applies to another another table, e.g., `Base\Bar` and `Bar` respectively. I could add the necessary attributes/methods to the `Base` classes but they can be regenerated. By using a *middle-class*

```
class Foo extends MyClass {}

class MyClass extends Base\Foo
{
    //must be created for each Foo, Bar, Buzz, 
    //they must extend Base/Foo, Base/Bar, Base/Buzz respectively
}
```

What is the best way (in terms of propel) to have the single extendible class? Should [behaviours](http://propelorm.org/documentation/06-behaviors.html) be used?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. Are you trying to add a set of methods to all generated classes?

Comment: @chocochaos yes, exactly. IMHO, the best way to do it is behaviours. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, probably. I haven't worked with behaviours myself though. You could also accomplish the same by creating a trait with the desired methods. Not as pretty as behaviours though :)

Comment: @chocochaos tried to work with behaviours. They seem to be the solution I was looking for. Will provide an answer soon :)